# Count values based on data range in R

Tags: r, count, aggregate, tidyverse

I have data that I want to aggregate based on data range.

```
have=data.frame('foo' = c(123,123,234534,2541,23,2541,2541,234534,234534),bar=as.Date(c('2020-01-13','2019-12-13','2020-02-14','2020-01-10','2020-01-03','2019-12-18','2019-11-06','2019-11-14','2019-10-20')))
```

```
     foo        bar
1    123 2020-01-13
2    123 2019-12-13
3 234534 2020-02-14
4   2541 2020-01-10
5     23 2020-01-03
6   2541 2019-12-18
7   2541 2019-11-06
8 234534 2019-11-14
9 234534 2019-10-20
```

I want to count column *foo* based on the interval that is max for distinct values of *foo* and a month back.

```
want=data.frame('foo' = c(123,234534,2541,23,2541,234534),bar=as.Date(c('2020-01-13','2020-02-14','2020-01-10','2020-01-03','2019-11-06','2019-11-14')),'count'=c(2,1,2,1,1,2))
```

```
     foo        bar count
1    123 2020-01-13     2
2 234534 2020-02-14     1
3   2541 2020-01-10     2
4     23 2020-01-03     1
5   2541 2019-11-06     1
6 234534 2019-11-14     2
```

I use the following code, but don't know how to use the range in the summarise() function.

```
have %>% 
  mutate(bar= as.Date(bar)) %>% 
  group_by(foo) %>% 
  summarise(min_date=(max(bar) %m-% months(1)),max_date=max(bar),count = n())
```

The output is the following, where *234534* is counted as 3 instead 1 and then 2, as seen in dataframe **want**.

```
     foo min_date   max_date   count
   <dbl> <date>     <date>     <int>
1     23 2019-12-03 2020-01-03     1
2    123 2019-12-13 2020-01-13     2
3   2541 2019-12-10 2020-01-10     3
4 234534 2020-01-14 2020-02-14     3
```

Comment: Could you spell out a bit more clearly how you're making date ranges? And do you want to group by both foo and that interval? It might help to make a variable (like with `mutate`) that holds the intervals, at least temporarily to give you a better look at things

Comment: I don't understand your example: You state that you want to group elements by date 'a month back' but 2019-12-12 to 2020-01-13   is more than a month but you group them anyways together?! Maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: @camille I don't know how to make the range, but I calculate the date as this 
lybrary(lubridate)
min_date=(max(bar) %m-% months(1))
max_date=max(bar). I alse want to group by the range